# Dependency Injection and the Url object

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I'm making the leap from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 and am still fuzzy on some core concepts, particularly relating to dependency injection (DI). I've read plenty of tutorials and have a grasp on DI with services, but am unclear on using DI with something like `\Drupal::Url()`.

For instance, I am using the following code in a class:

`use Drupal\Core\Url;
...
$url = Url::fromRoute('<current>', [], ['absolute' => 'true'])->toString();`

From what I can tell, there is no Url service. So, what I am wondering is: Is it possible to access Url via DI? And if so, how?

**Bonus points**: I intend for the class I am writing to be used as a service. Does this have any impact on the answer?

**Edit:** Fixed erroneous code.

**Edit 2**: I should also point out that the purpose of this call is to retrieve the current absolute URL so that I can determine if it is HTTPS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inject the UrlGenerator as service and use [UrlGenerator::generateFromRoute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21UrlGeneratorInterface.php/function/UrlGeneratorInterface%3A%3AgenerateFromRoute/8.4.x), but in the linked doc you are discouraged to do so:

> @internal Should not be used in user code. Use \Drupal\Core\Url
>   instead.

So the code in your question to create an url object is OK for a service, but not the `toString()` method. Render the url only with this method when the page rendering process has started, for example in a theme.

In a service you usually don't know this and you should return an unrendered url object, so that it can be rendered later in the rendering pipeline.

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('<current>', [], ['absolute' => 'true']);
```

`toString()` in the wrong place generates ugly error messages about early rendering which are hard to debug when this happens somewhere in a service.

Comment: Awesome! This is great information, especially about avoiding toString(). So, am I to understand correctly that it is acceptable to use the static Url::fromRoute procedurally and without DI?

Comment: "The Url class is basically a value object, so in that sense doesn't need to be injected. It's only when you render it to a string that the UrlGenerator dependency is pulled in. But you basically shouldn't be rendering it yourself - use a link render array."  https://www.drupal.org/node/2491981#comment-11556477 - #36

Comment: I really appreciate this information. I've edited my question to add clarification. Does the 2nd edit impact this answer?

Comment: No, because this would be about how to inject the request stack, get the current request and then `$request->getScheme()`

Comment: Do you think that is a good idea to inject the renderer service and then render the link render array inside the service?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, this depends on where the service is used. Like the render service itself  other services which depend on it should not run too early.

Comment: Hm... I'm a bit in the dark about this question and it's answer, I know there exists a `url_generator` service. Shouldn't we be using that? And also, "... is basically a value object, ...", it seems to me that you might want to mock routes for `url_generator` to be able to write decent unit tests, right? Or am I completely wrong here?